# python-3: how to create a new pandas column as subtraction of two consecutive rows of another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
x
1
3
4
7
10
```

I want to create a new column `y` as `y[i] = x[i] - x[i-1]` (and `y[0] = x[0]`).

So the above data frame will become:

```
x y
1 1
3 2
4 1
7 3
10 3
```

How to do that with python-3? Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.shift()` and `fillna()`:

```
df['y'] = (df['x'] - df['x'].shift(1)).fillna(df['x'])
```

To explain what this is doing, if we `print(df['x'].shift(1))` we get the following series:

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    7.0
```

Which is your values from `'x'` shifted down one row. The first row gets `NaN` because there is no value above it to shift down. So, when we do:

```
print(df['x'] - df['x'].shift(1))
```

We get:

```
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
```

Which is your subtracted values, but in our first row we get a `NaN` again. To clear this, we use `.fillna()`, telling it that we want to just take the value from `df['x']` whenever a null value is encountered.